# Is there a free mapping software for high-precision maps based on lidar point cloud data and GPS?

Tags: matlab, testing, gps, lidar, vehicle-routing

An autonomous driving platform is being built recently. I need to create a high-resolution map myself. I installed 128-line lidar and high-precision inertial navigation system, but I don’t know how to use which tools to create a high-precision map.
Is there a free mapping software for high-precision maps based on lidar point cloud data and GPS latitude and longitude information? Can Matlab do this?

Comment: Matlab's Image Processing and Computer Vision toolbox should be able to help you, BUT it's not free

Comment: @Jacob K Thanks.  We bought the genuine Maltab. I will try to build a high-precision map with matlab. Have you done the same thing?

Comment: I've only worked with Lidar Point Cloud Data alone, and not combined with GPS